# Selenium webdriver (c#) - Finding button based on attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to get a handle on the button below based on the attribute `gl-command`.  I'm aware I can find the button using a `Cssselector` by locator but I don't want to do that in this case.

I should point out that this is just one of many buttons within the AUT: `<google-componentbutton size="32"></google-componentbutton>`

```
<div class="gl-component-buttons"><gl-component-buttons id="gl-component-button-set-bottom">
  <google-componentbutton size="32">
    <button class="google-componentbutton glmdl-button glmdl-js-button glmdl-js-ripple-effect google-image gl-transaction-image" style="height: 32px; widgl: 32px; background-size: 24px 24px; background-position: 4px 4px;" gl-tooltip-id="google_component_transaction" gl-tooltip="transaction" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple" gl-command="transaction">  
      <span class="glmdl-button__ripple-container">
        <span class="glmdl-ripple"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
  </google-componentbutton>
```

Answer (score 11):

use xpath for based on the attribute "gl-command"

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@gl-command='transaction']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a custom selector with a method that returns your needed By selector for easy future use like this:

```
public static By SelectorByAttributeValue(string p_strAttributeName, string p_strAttributeValue)
{
    return (By.XPath(String.Format("//*[@{0} = '{1}']", 
                                   p_strAttributeName, 
                                   p_strAttributeValue)));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
driver.FindElement(Selectors.SelectorByAttributeValue("data-power","5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

XPath would be your safest bet.

```
IWebElement glButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@gl-command, 'transaction')]));
```

There's a similar question here: http://forum.testproject.io/index.php?topic=66.0

Comment: Tks this was exactly what i was looking for +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are asking to find a button IF it has the gl-command attribute or if the value of gl-command is some specific value so I'll answer both ways.

**Find buttons with gl-command attribute**

```
driver.FindElements(By.Tag("button")).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("gl-command")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can remove the `FirstOrDefault()` if you want all buttons with gl-command attribute.

**Find buttons with specific gl-command value**

```
driver.FindElements(By.Tag("button")).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("gl-command") && string.Compare(x.GetAttribute("gl-command"), "YOURGLCMD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0));
```

My closing parens might be off because I typed all this out on my phone in bed, but that's the general gist and my gf is yelling at me to go to sleep.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387630/dmitry-k  What is the using directive for .Where?  I get 'IWebElement does not contain definition...'

Answer (score 0):

If one of the class is unique you can use `className`

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("google-componentbutton"));
// or
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("glmdl-button"));
// etc
```

If none of them unique you can use combination of all of them or some of them

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".google-componentbutton.glmdl-button.glmdl-js-button.glmdl-js-ripple-effect.google-image.gl-transaction-image"));
// or
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".google-componentbutton.glmdl-button"));
```