# Selenium driver - find elements containing data attribute (HTML5)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

So, imagine a page that has the following HTML:

```
<button data-my-custom='{"fileName":"SomethingRandom.zip"}'>
                 Download build 1023
</button>
```

There will be several of these on the page, each will have a different filename value for the data-my-custom HTML 5 attribute.

How can I get the elements that contain the HTML5 attribute "data-my-custom" in Selenium?

I cannot figure out if I should use XPATH and if so, what the expression would be?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver (c#) - Finding button based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425466/selenium-webdriver-c-finding-button-based-on-attribute)

Comment: The xpath expression would be `//button[@data-my-custom]`.

Comment: For CSS-path, the selector will be: `button[data-my-custom]`, or `button[data-my-custom=<{yourFileNameObject}>]` if you want to find a specific one.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.... (without the @symbol)

Answer (score 0):

For CSS-path, the selector will be: `button[data-my-custom]`, or `button[data-my-custom=<{yourFileNameObject}>]` if you want to find a specific one.

Full credit to iamdanchiv.