# Using Selenium and C# - how to populate textbox when there is no ID or NAME

Tags: c#, selenium

I know this is going to be a rookie question, but I've spent 2 days on this and I'm desperate.

There are two textboxes on a page I need to populate. They are:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchCtrl.name" placeholder="Name or CRD#" flex="auto" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid flex-auto ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="firm-input" ng-model="searchCtrl.firm" placeholder="Firm Name or CRD# (optional)" flex="auto" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid flex-auto ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
```

I can populate the 2nd textbox using:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("acIndividualLocationId")).SendKeys("Sugar Grove, IL");
```

But as you can see, there is no ID or NAME for the 1st textbox. And I cannot get the CssSelector, TagName, or XPath to work (not sure why).

I can populate the 2nd textbox, THEN move the focus to the 1st textbox by:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("acIndividualLocationId")).SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.Tab);
```

So here's the rub: how do I populate the 1st textbox now that I have the focus on it???

ENVIRONMENT:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019
- C#
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.3900

Thanks in advance…

Comment: Hi Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425466/selenium-webdriver-c-finding-button-based-on-attribute

Comment: ^^^^ should answer your question. Use any or all of the attributes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium webdriver (c#) - Finding button based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425466/selenium-webdriver-c-finding-button-based-on-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand Your filling So many time i face this kind of issue specially when angular is there and finally i found one solution.

here you can use Xpath or use Javascript.

1.using Javascript :

```
    var script = @" try{
                            var appEleWrap = document.getElementsByClassName(Your class name);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                scopeWrap = angular.element(appEleWrap).scope();
                                if(!scopeWrap.$$phase){
                                    scopeWrap.$apply(function(){
                                        scopeWrap.searchCtrl.name = '{0}';
                                        scopeWrap.searchCtrl.firm='{1}';
                                     }); 
                                }
                            }, 1000);
                          }catch(e){ alert(e.message); }
                      ";
        string evalScript = string.Empty;
        evalScript = script.Replace("{0}", "Your Text");
        evalScript = evalScript.Replace("{1}", "Your Text");
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript(evalScript);
```

2.using Xpath : find List of element. based on index you can populate text box

```
var ListOfElm = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type,'text')]")).ToList();
        if (ListOfElm != null)
        {
            ListOfElm[0].SendKeys("");//Based on index ok.
            ListOfElm[1].SendKeys("");
        }
```

I hope this will help you
Thank You.

Comment: Thank you Amar. I used your solution #2. Gave me exactly what I needed.  

I'm new to Windows desktop programming - years of IBM mainframes and ASP.Net, but this is a challenge. I definitely need a better understanding of XPath...